# Fill form.select with chekboxes and data from another model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a product model and a category model in a Ruby on Rails project. The product model I specified `has_many :categories`, and inside the product_controller.rb, in the create action I created a variable `@categories = Category.all`. The categories would be things like "Winter, summer, spring, wool, yarn, cotton, etc", how could I use those values to put together a select with checkboxes inside to be able to create a new product that has those categories associated with it? I tried multiple ways but I can't figure it out.

Comment: You're asking for a select element that has check boxes as list items, yes? Rails doesn't have a helper that works that way, since HTML doesn't allow check boxes as list items. You can, however, find similar things in libraries like [bootstrap](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/#basic-examples).

Comment: So, you seem to be asked either (or both!) of two different things: (1) how do you build a list of `select` `options` from your model; or (2) how do you style a list of `select` `options` so that they look like checkboxes. Which of these is your main issue right now? As @MarsAtomic already said: checkboxes aren't `select` `options` in HTML.

Comment: @MarsAtomic i think my issue is the first one, but the thing is I need to select multiple values to associate, not only one

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it sounds as though the mention of checkboxes was an artifact of the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). What you really want is the ability to associate multiple categories to a single product via a select element, or even more simply, you want to know how to enable multiple selection in one select.

The HTML select tag has a `multiple` option, and the [API documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select) shows you how it works:

`select(object, method, choices = nil, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block) public`

The html_options section of the method signature is where you want to pass a `multiple` option. In your case, it would be something like this:

`<%= form.select(:categories, @categories, {}, { multiple: true} ) %>`

The params hash you get in your controller's `create` or `update` should contain a `params[:categories]` hash of your user's selections.